# OpenCV - Accessing Mat data using for loop

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I'm trying to create a convolution function but I'm having trouble during the access to the kernel data (cv::Mat).

I create the 3x3 kernel:

```
  cv::Mat krn(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
  krn.setTo(1);
  krn = krn/9;
```

And I try to loop over it. Next the `image` Mat will be the image to which I want to apply the convolution operator and output will be the result of convolution:

```
     for (int r = 0; r < image.rows - krn.rows; ++r) {

        for (int c = 0; c < image.cols - krn.cols; ++c) {

        int sum = 0;

        for (int rs = 0; rs < krn.rows; ++rs) {
          for (int cs = 0; cs < krn.cols; ++cs) {

            sum += krn.data[rs * krn.cols + cs] * image.data[(r + rs) * image.cols + c + cs];
          }
        }
        output.data[(r+1)*src.cols + c + 1]=sum;  // assuming 3x3 kernel
    }
  }
```

However the output is not as desired (only randomic black and white pixel).
However, if I change my code this way:

```
for (int r = 0; r < image.rows - krn.rows; ++r) {
    
            for (int c = 0; c < image.cols - krn.cols; ++c) {
    
            int sum = 0;
    
            for (int rs = 0; rs < krn.rows; ++rs) {
              for (int cs = 0; cs < krn.cols; ++cs) {
    
                sum += 0.11 * image.data[(r + rs) * image.cols + c + cs];           // CHANGE HERE
              }
            }
            output.data[(r+1)*src.cols + c + 1]=sum;  // assuming 3x3 kernel
        }
      }
```

Using `0.11` instead of the kernel values seems to give the correct output.
For this reason I think I'm doing something wrong accessing the kernel's data.

P.S: I cannot use `krn.at<float>(rs,cs)`.

Thanks!

Comment: krn.at<float>(rs,cs) - try to access kernel data this way

Comment: Thanks, I will add to the main post, but I cannot use that.

Comment: float* kernel_float_data = (float*)krn.data - and then access your kernel as you do.

Comment: Nice, thank you! In your opinion, is there another way with the opencv convertTo() function? Thanks!

Comment: convertTo() method does not influence on type of "data" field.

Comment: @Hihikomori Thanks again for your help. I'm comparing my results using 5x5 kernel and the filter2D() function. However, my results seems to be wrong. Looking at the code, do you have any idea of what I'm missing? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of needlessly using `memcpy`, you can just *cast* the pointer. I'll use a C-style cast because why not.

```cpp
cv::Mat krn = 1 / (cv::Mat_<float>(3,3) <<
    1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
    7, 8, 9);

for (int i = 0; i < krn.rows; i += 1)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < krn.cols; j += 1)
    {
        // to see clearly what's happening
        uint8_t *byteptr = krn.data + krn.step[0] * i + krn.step[1] * j;
        float *floatptr = (float*) byteptr;

        // or in one step:
        float *floatptr = (float*) (krn.data + krn.step[0] * i + krn.step[1] * j);

        cout << "krn.at<float>(" << i << "," << j << ") = " << (*floatptr) << endl;
endl;
    }
}
```

```
krn.at<float>(0,0) = 1
krn.at<float>(0,1) = 0.5
krn.at<float>(0,2) = 0.333333
krn.at<float>(1,0) = 0.25
krn.at<float>(1,1) = 0.2
krn.at<float>(1,2) = 0.166667
krn.at<float>(2,0) = 0.142857
krn.at<float>(2,1) = 0.125
krn.at<float>(2,2) = 0.111111
```

Note that pointer arithmetic may not be obvious. if you have a `uint8_t*`, adding `1` moves it by **one uint8_t**, and if you have a `float*`, adding `1` moves it by **one float** which is **four** bytes. The `step[]` contains offsets expressed in bytes.

Consult [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) for details, which include information on the `step[]` array that contains the strides/steps to calculate the offset given a tuple of indices into the matrix.

Comment: Thank you. I prefer this method to the memcpy one.

Comment: Could I ask you one more thing? I'm comparing my results using 5x5 kernel and the filter2D() function. However, my results seems to be wrong. Looking at the code, do you have any idea of what I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: yes, in your code you are accessing the *float* data from am *uint8_t* (uchar) pointer (`image.data` and `krn.data`)... that will give you garbage. apply what I've shown and the issue will resolve.

Comment: you ought to find learning materials for C++. this is basic C++, even basic C. `*floatptr = something`

Answer (score 1):

`cv::Mat::data` is pointer of type `uchar`.

By `data[y * cols + x]` you access some byte of stored `float` values in `krn`. To get full float values use `at` method template:

```
krn.at<float>(rs,cs)
```

Consider changing type of `sum` variable to be real. Without this, you may lose partial results when calculating convolution .

---

So, if you cannot use `at`, just read 4 bytes from data pointer:

```
float v = 0.0;
memcpy(&v, krn.data + (rs * krn.step + cs * sizeof(float)), 4);
```

`step` - means total bytes occupied by one line in mat.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. However as an exercise, I cannot use `krn.at<float>`. Would you suggest another method?

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I'm comparing my results using 5x5 kernel and the filter2D() function. However, my results seems to be wrong. Looking at the code, do you have any idea of what I'm missing? Thanks again!